# Select Part of a boundary mesh

Tags: mesh

I would like to pick a part of a boundary mesh, for example

```
bm=BoundaryMesh[Cuboid[]]
```

Is it possible to select the part(side) `x==1` of the cuboid and define a new 2D-mesh of this side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) package can help you with `SelectElements` function and some manual postprocessing.

```
Needs["MeshTools`"]

bm = ToBoundaryMesh[Cuboid[]]

side = SelectElements[bm, #1 == 1 &]
```

This "projects" 3D mesh with `"BoundaryElements"` to 2D mesh with `"MeshElements"`. `Reverse` on element incidents is necessary to avoid warning messages about bad their quality (inverted elements).

```
mesh2D = ToElementMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> side["Coordinates"][[All, {2, 3}]],
  "MeshElements" -> MapAt[Reverse, side["BoundaryElements"], {All, 1, All}]
]

mesh2D["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm@LightBlue]]
```

[image: mesh2D]

Comment: Thanks for this helpful tool, I'll try to select the side mesh.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract information about meshes using functions like `MeshCells` and `MeshCoordinates`.

```
bm = BoundaryMesh[Cuboid[]]
sel = Select[MeshCoordinates[bm], #[[1]] == 1&]
hull = ConvexHullMesh[sel[[All, 2;;3]]]
```

[image: Output of convex hull.]

You might also be able to get away with using `Polygon` instead of `ConvexHullMesh` if your 2D mesh isn't always convex, but you'd have to be able to order the points of `sel` first.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting ideas. I hoped to find a function which easily creates a submesh.